# To find when $\sqrt{\frac{7^{n}+1}{2}}$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, radicals

Find all $n$ such that
$\sqrt{\frac{7^{n}+1}{2}}$ is a prime.

I have tried elementary methods like factorising and using $\pmod{7}$ and so on, but with no luck. I think this question could be approached using Pell's Equation. By trial and error, one can see that $n=1,2$ is a solution. I require a rigorous solution finding all such $n$. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It is easy to see that if that is prime then $n$ must be a power of $2$. Not clear how to eliminate the other powers of 2.

Comment: I was only able to prove n as even. How do you prove as power of 2.

Comment: Uh ... what happens if $n$ is a power of $2$ greater than or equal to $4$ and you render the radicand $\bmod 13$?

Comment: Write $n=2^k(2m+1)$. Then $2p^2=7^n+1=(7^{2^k})^{2m+1}+1$ is divisible by $7^{2^k}+1$. Since this is even, and at least $8$, the only possibilities are $$7^{2^k}+1=2p \\ 7^{2^k}+1=2p^2$$ Now just show that the first case is impossible.

Comment: Note here that if $m >1$ then $2p^2= (7^{2^k})^{2m+1}+1> ( 7^{2^k}+1)^2$ which means that the former cannot be $2p$.

Comment: A stronger statement seems to be true , namely that $\frac{7^n+1}{2}$ is not a perfect square for $n>2$ (This is true upto at least $n=10^5$). Moreover, if it helps, it can be shown that $p$ must be a Wieferich prime to base $7$ (We must have $p^2\mid 7^{p-1}-1$)